# Cannot use a Makefile to comple kernel files in Ubuntu Linux on WSL

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some C code and a Makefile for that C code. The C program is called `simple.c` and the the makefile is just called `Makefile`.

Here are the contents of simple.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
 
/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int simple_init(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Kernel Module\n");
 
   return 0;
}
 
/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void simple_exit(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Kernel Module\n");
}
 
/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");
```

And this is the content of the Makefile:

```
obj-m += simple.o  
all:    
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules  
clean:      
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I have both of them in the same directory and I use the instruction make to compile it however it does not work and I get this error message:
`make -C /lib/modules/5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build M=/home/eddie modules make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build: No such file or directory.  Stop. make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2`

I have tried to install some things I have seen online for linux kernal but they do not seem to work.

I have tried the following:
`sudo apt install linux-tools-virtual hwdata`
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

It's important to note that these all do sucessfully install. When I use `lsmod` to list all current kernal modules nothing is listed.

Am I doing anything wrong? Missing a command to install something? I am using Ubuntu Linux subsystem for linux on windows 11

Comment: What is wrong with the formatting?

Comment: There is no modules support in the standard WSL kernel. See e.g. [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594470/wsl-2-does-not-have-lib-modules).

Comment: I ended up using a VM and I get a new error `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.` what could this mean

Comment: it depends, but try indenting your lines with a tab character (not space characters). Good luck.